# Set InArgument value from a cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working in a workflow foundation project and I find a trouble. I explain my project:

- I have a MainWindow where I set the workflowname that I would like to run. When I run this workflow I call VisualTracking.cs class to see where the debug is. This cs class constructor has the following method (WorkflowDesigner wd,string filePath,string name)
  The name is the workflowname that i set in mainwindow.
- I have a dll project with some custom activities that I use in the previous rehosted workflow. In one of these activities I have a InArgument that It's call textValue. I would like that this InArgument get the workflowname value, So to do It I do the following code:

MainWindow:

```
    ......
    VisualTracking tracker = new VisualTracking(wd, workflowFilePathName, this.workflowName);
    .....
```

VisualTracking class:

```
    .......
    private string workflowName { get; set; }
    .......
    public VisualTracking(WorkflowDesigner wd,string filePath,string name) {
    .......
    foreach (Activity v in idActivityMap.Values)
        {
            string val = v.GetType().FullName;
            activityLists.Add(val);
            if (v.GetType().FullName == "RulesDll.Status_Activity.StatusActivity")
            {
                ((StatusActivity)v).textValue = this.workflowName;                   
            }
        }
    ........
```

In this foreach for each workflow activity i check if his namespace is the target activity that i want to set the workflowname.

StatusActivity

```
    ........
    public InArgument<string> textValue;

    public InArgument<string> Text
    {
        get { return this.textValue; }
        set { this.textValue = value; }
    }
    ........
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
       ...........
        string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);
       ...........
```

So I would like that in string text has the workflowName value that i associated in visualtracking class.... But When I debug, always retrieve a value as a null....

Any solution will be appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When is `workflowName` set in your VisualTracking class?  It appears to me that you are passing in the desired value when you create the instance from your MainWindow, but you never actually set it.  I'm guessing that you actually want to use the value passed in to the `name` parameter from MainWnidow.  I would recommend you replace the following lines of code:

```
if (v.GetType().FullName == "RulesDll.Status_Activity.StatusActivity")
{
    ((StatusActivity)v).textValue = this.workflowName;
}
```

with these:

```
// This will also catch cases where your class inherits
// from StatusActivity.
StatusActivity activity = v as StatusActivity;

// Using 'as' cast will return null if the type cannot be 
// cast to a StatusActivity.
if (activity != null)
{
    // You passed in a reference to MainWindow's "this.workflowName" 
    // in the name parameter of this constructor.
    activity.textValue = name;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put this.workflowName = name; in visualTracking class ;-), but Still didn't work